# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WASX7122E: Expected "-" not found

Tags: java, deployment, websphere, jython, wsadmin

I can update the application manually by this command

```
AdminApp.update('CUSWS', 'app',  'the options below')
```

but when I update from the jython script

```
appName = '\'' +appName+ '\''
updatetype = '\'app\''
appOptions = \'' +options+ '\''
AdminApp.update(appName, updatetype, appOptions )
```

I got an error below.

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WASX7122E: Expected "-"  not found.

 '[ -operation update -contents /data/CUSWS-uat-20141106.war -nopreCompileJSPs -installed.ear.destination $(APP_INSTALL_ROOT)/cusws1cell01 -distributeApp -nouseMetaDataFromBinary -nodeployejb -createMBeansForResources -noreloadEnabled -nodeployws -validateinstall warn -noprocessEmbeddedConfig -filepermission .*\.dll=755#.*\.so=755#.*\.a=755#.*\.sl=755 -noallowDispatchRemoteInclude -noallowServiceRemoteInclude -asyncRequestDispatchType DISABLED -nouseAutoLink -noenableClientModule -clientMode isolated -novalidateSchema -contextroot /CUSWS -MapModulesToServers [[ "Apache-Axis" CUSWS-uat-20141106.war,WEB-INF/web.xml WebSphere:cell=cusws1cell01,cluster=cuswsGWCluster+WebSphere:cell=cusws1cell01,node=cuswsIHSnode1,server=webserver1 ]] -MapWebModToVH [[ "Apache-Axis" CUSWS-uat-20141106.war,WEB-INF/web.xml default_host ]] -CtxRootForWebMod [[ "Apache-Axis" CUSWS-uat-20141106.war,WEB-INF/web.xml /CUSWS ]]]'
```

I've tried to solve this problem for 2 days but can't find the mistake.
What do I miss ?
Please help, Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

Removing the bracket symbol [ and ] at first and end of the update option solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Clear the `wsadmin.traceout` log. Then run this manually and via script and compare logs. It should give you some more hints whats wrong with the script.